# How to namespace folder in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

how would one put everything in `app/presenters` under `Presenters` namespace?

so `app/presenters/admin/article.rb`  containing

```
module Presenters
  module Admin
    class Article
    end
  end
end
```

may be available as `Presenters::Admin::Article` ?

Comment: Depends how deep you want to go. But going 2 levels deep seems a bit drastic. Do you really need such a structure? And to answer your question, yes, the class would be available as `Presenters::Admin::Article`

Comment: Looks like, it won't work that way - Rails will try to lookup Presenters::Admin::Article in app/*/presenters/admin/article.rb, so corresponding structure will be app/presenters/presenters/admin/article.rb

Comment: That's not right. It should look, if you call it like `Presenters::Admin::Article`, in `app/presenters/admin/article.rb` . Also, make sure you're not doing anything special in `application.rb` to load the presenters folder because Rails automatically considers everything in the `app/` folder.

Comment: Maybe try calling it like: `Admin::Article`

Comment: did you try to lookup ApplicationController, for example, that way? `Controllers::ApplicationController`?

Answer (score -1):

Here's the working answer:

`app/presenters/admin/article.rb`

```
module Admin
  class Article

  end
end
```

access like: `Admin::Article.new`